# Convert file to binary in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to write a program that transfers a file through sound (kind of like a fax). I broke up my program into several steps:

1. convert file to binary
2. convert 1 to a certain tone and 0 to another
3. play the tones to another computer
4. other computer listens to tones
5. other computer converts tones into binary
6. other computer converts binary into file.

However, I can't seem to find a way to convert a file to binary. I found a way to convert a string to binary using

```
public static string StringToBinary(string data)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in data.ToCharArray())
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8,'0'));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

From http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/convert-string-to-binary-and-binary-to-string-in-c/ .
But I can't find out how to convert a file to binary (the file could be of any extension).

So, how can I convert a file to binary? Is there a better way for me to write my program?

Comment: why don't you open the file in binary mode?

Comment: Looks like Ashkan has got your answer for you. +1 for a cool concept for a project.

Comment: All files _are_ binary.

Comment: Just curious, what's the application for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why don't you just open the file in binary mode?
this function opens the file in binary mode and returns the byte array:

```
private byte[] GetBinaryFile(filename)
{
     byte[] bytes;
     using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {
          bytes = new byte[file.Length];
          file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
     }
     return bytes;
}
```

then to convert it to bits:

```
byte[] bytes = GetBinaryFile("filename.bin");
BitArray bits = new BitArray(bytes);
```

now bits variable holds 0,1 you wanted.

or you can just do this:

```
private BitArray GetFileBits(filename)
{
     byte[] bytes;
     using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {
          bytes = new byte[file.Length];
          file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
     }
     return new BitArray(bytes);
}
```

Or even shorter code could be:

```
   private BitArray GetFileBits(filename)
    {
         byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
         return new BitArray(bytes);
    }
```

Comment: I did that and I got an array of digits between 1 and 255 (a byte) so should I then convert each digit to base 2 and add as many zeros to the left as needed so that it is 8 bits long it is there another way?

Comment: @Daniel the last function I have written just gets the filename and gives you 0 and 1 you wanted

Comment: how i get back my file

Comment: Or just `File.ReadAllBytes(filename)`

Comment: Is there a (big) difference between opening a MemoryStream and doing a Read() operation to get the byte array, and calling the File.ReadAllBytes() method? Thanks!

Comment: @clamum No big difference as ReadAllBytes itself uses stream to read it, however I always use ReadAllBytes as it is much easier