# How to insert or update large data into varchar(max) using EF 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 and SQL Server 2012. I have a table which contains text files in a `varchar(max)` column. Average file size is a few MBs but I am looking for a solution that will work for larger files too. I add or update this column using string data type but I don't think this is efficient way to update a few thousand records where each record is 4 to 5 Mb. Is there any efficient way to insert or update large data types in EF (or even in ADO.net)?

Comment: What's your expectation for "efficient"?  A "few thousand" files at "4 to 5 MB" each is roughly 10GB.  Your network I/O is going to be the bottleneck here, not your C# code.

Comment: you can use blob but the efficient way is to save file on HDD rather than DB.

Comment: @DStanley since EF will load every row to update and will concatenate string so it will be using lot of memory

Comment: @rashfmnb actually not every time. file opening and file closing operations are very slow

Comment: @ZubaerNaseem So you're concatenating new data with the existing data?

Comment: @DStanley yes if record for the give date already exits then new data is appended otherwise inserted

Comment: @ZubaerNaseem I think you're going to have a lot of I/O no matter what you do then.  One alternative is to insert to a temp table and then join to do the concat or insert on the SQL side.  Or store the files on a file server and just store the paths in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a stored procedure which uses write function of varchar(max). I was able to make my code 10x faster by calling SP instead of updating EF object. This SP then executes query similar to

```
update MyTable set col1.Write(@data, @oldLength, @data_length)
```

Answer (score 0):

For large files the field can be changed to varbinary(max) and the files can be converted into binary format and inserted into the database. For files that are greater than 1MB,Filestreams provide a better option. Try to visit [Convert file to binary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106687/convert-file-to-binary-in-c-sharp) for binary conversion.

Comment: how is this efficient?