# converting file to binary c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert file into binary. I tried, but I get 0X000000000000000..... It is not correct. Always every file getting that digits. Please help me to solve thanks in advance

```
if (value.resume_file.CompareTo("") != 0)
{
    byte[] binary = new byte[value.resume_file.Length];
    //binary =  Convert.ToByte(value.resume_file);
    objJobSeekers.IsResume = true;
    objJobSeekers.DocFileName = value.resume_file;
    objJobSeekers.Resume = binary;
    objJobSeekers.TypedResume = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Comment: What is `value.resume_file`, please post complete code.

Comment: So for a file with a filename that is X characters long, you reserve X bytes of binary content? Good programming...

Comment: but i am getting 0x000 how to solve that. will u help me  Peter B

Comment: This is not google. Suggested search terms: `.NET read file bytes`

Comment: Maybe will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106687/convert-file-to-binary-in-c-sharp

Comment: It's hard to give any help when you don't say what type of variable "value.resume_file" actually is, you pluck something called "objJobSeekers" out of thin air, you don't say *where* you're seeing 0X000000000000000.   All that this code snippet seems to do is allocate an array of bytes of a given size, but it makes no attempt to read any file data into this buffer (so no wonder it contains zeros).

Comment: `Convert.ToByte(...)` tries to convert the argument into a *single* byte. It doesn't know about "files" and it cannot return a byte array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

string to byte[]

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

byte[] to string

```
str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: And note that "str" is string contents, not a filename.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read any file from disk and get its bytes then use

```
string FileDir = "D:\\File.doc";
byte[] MyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(FileDir);
```

If you want to convert some random object in memory into bytes then you can use a BinarySerializer

```
byte[] MyBytes;
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
    MyBytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```