# Convert file to binary (11111111110) then do the reverse path to get the image

Tags: c#, binary, jpeg, corrupt

I have a jpg image that I can convert into a sequence of binary numbers but I can't recover it afterward. It ends up corrupted.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputFilename = "test.jpg";
            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilename);

            var test =  ToBinaryString(fileBytes);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(test);  
            string fileresult = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            byte[] fileresutl2 = Convert.FromBase64String(fileresult);


            File.WriteAllBytes("C:/Users/Florian/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net5.0/test7.txt", fileresutl2);
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/Florian/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net5.0/test7.txt");

            var result =  Convert.ToBase64String(FromBinaryString(text));
            File.WriteAllBytes("C:/Users/Florian/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net5.0/test8.jpg", FromBinaryString(test));
            Console.WriteLine(test);
        }
        
        public static string ToBinaryString(byte[] array)
        {
            var s = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in array)
                s.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2));

            return s.ToString();
        }
        
        public static byte[] FromBinaryString(string s)  
        {
            int count = s.Length / 8;
            var b = new byte[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
                b[i] = Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i * 8, 8), 2);

            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see what can corrupt my file.
Excuse me for the organization of the file, it is simply a test code coded quickly.

Comment: Did you mean to write "result" to disk rather than calling "FromBinaryString" twice?

Comment: the result is written on the disk but impossible to open the image it is corrupted FromBinaryString is called only once

Comment: So a few things for you to investigate alongside the answer written below. You read in the file bytes, then convert that to a binary string, then get the ASCII bytes of the binary string, then convert the ASCII bytes to Base 64 and back and then store the result into a text file. Then when you read the text file you just try to write a byte array to disk again. It seems over-complicated. Perhaps you can use the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106687/convert-file-to-binary-in-c-sharp/24106735

Answer (score 0):

There are some odd things in the code such as uselessly converting to base64 and back, but let's go right to the core of the problem: converting bytes to a binary string

```
public static string ToBinaryString(byte[] array)
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in array)
        s.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2));

    return s.ToString();
}
```

On the face of it, it seems reasonable. Bytes go in, a binary string comes out. But here are some examples that I hope will convince you that there is an issue with this conversion:

```
Console.WriteLine(ToBinaryString(new byte[]{1, 1}));
Console.WriteLine(ToBinaryString(new byte[]{3}));
```

( https://ideone.com/y6dB1Z )

These both come out as "11". That's bad, it means the conversion is not reversible. The reason it goes wrong is that the most-significant zeroes are dropped, and then the next byte "shifts into" that position. Every byte should be represented by exactly 8 bits, just as your decoding function expects. For example:

```
public static string ToBinaryString(byte[] array)
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in array)
        s.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));

    return s.ToString();
}
```

By the way it's not like you should actually ever *use* something like this (except when experimenting, which it looks like is what you're doing, so it's OK), it inflates the file size by a factor of 8 and doesn't actually do anything useful. If you're going to decode the JPG for example, do that directly with the bytes of the file, not with "the file as a binary string". Even Huffman codes should not be done like that.

Comment: thank you its work
I had indeed done my initial conversion wrong